# How to define an non-JTA datasource for JPA-Hibernate? org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider - Could not find datasource:

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, jpa-2.0

I am trying to change my web-app's JDBC code to JPA using Hibernate as provider. I am using Eclipse IDE. In that i have defined a MySQL data source. I added it in the persistence.xml.
But, I am getting the below error.

```
6640 [30289364@qtp-7494106-7] ERROR org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider  - Could not find datasource: tamSql
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException; remaining name 'tamSql'
```

**My persistence.xml looks like,**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="ExpensePersistentUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<non-jta-data-source>tamSql</non-jta-data-source>
    <class>com.pricar.JPAInteg.Role</class>
    <class>com.pricar.JPAInteg.User</class>
    <class>com.pricar.JPAInteg.Userdetail</class>
    <class>com.pricar.JPAInteg.Category</class>
    <class>com.pricar.JPAInteg.Expens</class>
    <class>com.pricar.JPAInteg.Leavetable</class>
    <class>com.pricar.JPAInteg.Permissiontoken</class>
    <class>com.pricar.JPAInteg.Roletokenassociation</class>
    <class>com.pricar.JPAInteg.UserPK</class>
<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/officemgmt"/>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"></property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="1234"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>

</properties>
```

Any Suggestions!!!
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you post the code of how you have declared JNDI name.

Comment: @Jaydeep: May you tell me what is JNDI name & where i have to declare it. I am very very new to JPA & Hibernate. Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You don't need `<non-jta-data-source>` when your datasource is configured in `<properties>`. `<non-jta-data-source>` is needed when datasource is configured in application server configuration and obtained via JNDI.

Comment: Ya, you are right. Thanks for your reply. I actually, miss understood the JPA/Hibernate Specification. It would be appreciative if you tell me that "shall i use Transaction type scope = "RESOURCE_LOCAL". Because of that only i added, <non-jta-data-source>.

Comment: Different transaction types and `<jta-data-source>`/`<non-jta-data-source>` make sense only when you use a full-blown application server (JBoss, WebSphere, WebLogic, etc). If you have a standalone application or servlet container (Tomcat, Jetty), you simply write `transaction-type = "RESOURCE_LOCAL"`.

Comment: Is there a way we can configure <non-jta-data-source> in eclipse or windows Machine, so that I don't need to use multiple persistence units for local/server