# Glassfish 3 with JPA configuration

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

I have use JPA with Hibernate in a standalone application but now I want to try with with an application server. I know GlassFish provides EclipseLink implementation for JPA but I have a few questions.

1. Do I need to specify in `persistence.xml` EclipseLink as a provider for my persistence-unit?
2. Does `persistence.xml` look the same as if it the application would not be deployed? If it does not look the same how does it look?
3. Do I need to specifically download the implementation jars for EclipseLink and build with them or does the container handles this after my application is deployed?
4. How do I specify the jdbc driver in `persistence.xml`?
5. Does my application need to be deployed as a `.ear`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't need to specify the persistence provider, by default the one contained in your application server will be used (if it has at least the Web profile, of course, otherwise servers such as Tomcat won't provide you EclipseLink).
2. Yes, it will have the same look (in both applications you are just using JPA the same way).
3. For your code to compile, you will only need to have persistence-api.jar in your classpath (if you use Maven, set the scope to "provided"). Then the server will automatically provide its implementation jars.
4. You could use a persistence unit like described in [this page](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/configuration.html) ("typical configuration in a Java SE environment"). But I would rather suggest you use a `<jta-data-source>` instead, that refers to a [datasource provided by GlassFish](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2432/gkyan.html).
5. As far as I can tell, it can also be a WAR file, I didn't have any problem deploying it (webapp as a Maven WAR module + beans in a JAR module).

Comment: The deployment seems to work with <jta-data-source>JdbcDriverResource</jta-data-source> although I do not really understand what JTA has to do with the jdbc driver?

Comment: You are configuring the whole data source, which is more than just a JDBC driver. If you prefer handling DB transactions by yourself, perhaps you should consider the <non-jta-data-source/> tag...

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753815/how-to-define-an-non-jta-datasource-for-jpa-hibernate-org-hibernate-connection

Comment: One more question; the EntityManager resource is created by default or do I need to create it from the Administrator Console as the JdbcPool and Jdbc Driver?

Comment: I think the EntityManager has nothing to do with the server configuration, it is automatically instantiated by your JPA provider once you declare you persistence unit and use it in you EJBs using `@PersistenceContext`. The only thing you have to configure in GlassFish is the Jdbc Resource + Connection Pool.